# What musical instruments does MIDI format on Android support?

Tags: android, midi

Does Android use `MIDI 1.0` or `General MIDI (GM)` to playback midi files?

https://www.midi.org/specifications

My app needs to support Android versions 2.0 - 7.0.

Answer (score 1):

The MIDI specification itself does not define any instruments.

There are various specifications and more-or-less official standards that define instrument sets, but the only one supported by Android's internal MIDI synthesizer is [General MIDI (GM 1)](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/general-midi) ([instrument list](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/gm-level-1-sound-set)).

Comment: Thanks. Where can I read more about the Android's internal MIDI synthesizer? I didn't find anything on https://developer.android.com/reference

Comment: The doc for [JetPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/JetPlayer.html) mentions General MIDI, but for details, you have to look at the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_external_sonivox).